# How do I have an alert box appear when using passthru?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am using a passthru file for an update to a database that is triggered by an ajax function.  Ajax is:

```
    $("#updateInventory").live('click', function() {
    $('#updateInventory').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "updateInventoryExecmws.php",//
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                                update = data.update;
                                console.log(data);
                                if (update == true){
                alert(data.message);
                                } else {
                                $('#message').html(data.saying);
                                   }
                            }

    });
});
```

and the passthru file is:

```
    <?php
passthru('php /home/bookcell/public_html/testbcos/mbas/updateInventorymws.php >> /home/bookcell/public_html/testbcos/exports/mbas.txt &');

$saying = array('saying' => 'Updating Inventory for today. An email will be sent as soon as the update is finished.');

echo json_encode($saying);
?>
```

This all works fine, and starts the updateInventorymws.php file.  Here I need to check if the update has already been done today and if it has alert the user and stop the script from executing.  Except for the alert, this all works correctly.  Here is the code for this:

```
    //inventory already been updated today?
$updatedTodayResult = $conn->query("SELECT * from order_sold where date_sold between NOW() - interval 5 minute and NOW()");

$updatedTodayRows = $updatedTodayResult->num_rows;
if($updatedTodayRows < 1){
    $updatedToday = false;
    $note = "Updating Inventory for today. An email will be sent as soon as the update is finished.";
}else{
    $updatedToday = true;
    $note = "Inventory is already updating for today.";

}
    if($updatedToday == false){
    // run the update here
    }
    $records = $x;

$to = "myemail@me.com";
$subject = "Update Inventory Report";
$body = $records . " records were successfully updated in today's inventory update!";
mail($to, $subject, $body);
$message = array('message' => $note,
      'update' => $updatedToday,
      );

}else{
$records1 = 'Someone has attempted to run Update Inventory more than once today. If this problem shouldn\'t occur, please see administrator.';

$to = "myemail@me.com";
$subject = "Update Inventory Report";
$body = $records1;
mail($to, $subject, $body);
$message = array('message' => $note,
      'update' => $updatedToday,
      );    
}

echo json_encode($message);
```

Is there a way to have it create an alert from this so the user knows the update was already done??

Comment: You would have to encode the message in your JSON response then use JS on the client to detect this message an call your alert function.

Comment: I had done that, the problem I think is that I am using two json_encodes and I need a way to process that.